# ¿Como puedo obtener un Id de un Div que esta dentro de otro Div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, clase

Como bien dice el titulo, me preguntaba como puedo obtener el id de un div que se encuentra dentro de otro div al hacer click, sobre dicho elemento. 
Me encuentro haciendo el siguiente menu: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que busco es que al clickear a algun elemento, me arroje dicho id. 
Este es mi Codigo

```
<div class="wrapper-content" id="Categoria">
            <div class="box" id="Music"><i class="icono fas fa-music"></i><p>Audio & Video</p></div>
            <div class="box b" id="Sport"><i class="icono fas fa-futbol"></i><p>Deportes</p></div>
            <div class="box c"id="Home"><i class="icono fas fa-home"></i><p>Hogar</p></div>
            <div class="box d" id="Games"><i class="icono fas fa-gamepad"></i><p>Videojuegos</p></div>
            <div class="box e" id="Tecno"><i class="icono fas fa-laptop"></i><p>Tecnologia</p></div>
            <div class="box f"  id="Licor"><i class="icono fas fa-beer"></i><p>Licores</p></div>
            <div class="box g" id="Tools"><i class="icono fas fa-toolbox"></i><p>Herramientas</p></div>
            <div class="box h" id="Instrumentos"><i class="icono fas fa-guitar"></i><p>Instrumentos</p></div>
            <div class="box i" id="Recaudo"><i class="icono fas fa-bus-alt"></i><p>Recaudo Monterrey</p></div>

        </div>
```

He intentado con:

```
$(function () {
$(document).on('click', 'div', function () {
       alert($(this).prop('id'));
    });
});
```

El Cual no me funciona porque si bien me encuentra el id que es, me trae toda la jerarquía de `Div` detrás de el (*Es decir Sport>Categoria>X>Y...)* 
 
Con un `Children()` sobre el ***Div Categorias*** pero  no me ha funcionado, ya que solamente me trae el *id de Musica* sin importar donde pulse en el menú. 
De antemano gracias, y disculpen por colocarlos a leer mucho.

Comment: Si todos tus divs hijos tienen la clase box por que no usas esa clase en tu evento click, así te aseguras de solo obtener el id de los div hijos. Por que en tu evento estas pidiendo el id de todos los divs donde des clic por eso te obtiene siempre el del padre y el del hijo.

Comment: Yo he probado tu código y me muestra dos alerts, uno con el padre y otro con el hijo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si todos tus divs hijos tienen la clase box por que no usas esa clase en tu evento click, así te aseguras de solo obtener el id de los div hijos. Por que en tu evento estas pidiendo el id de todos los divs donde des clic por eso te obtiene siempre el del padre y el del hijo.

```js
$(function () {
$(document).on('click', '.box', function () {
       alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-content" id="Categoria">
            <div class="box" id="Music"><i class="icono fas fa-music"></i><p>Audio & Video</p></div>
            <div class="box b" id="Sport"><i class="icono fas fa-futbol"></i><p>Deportes</p></div>
            <div class="box c"id="Home"><i class="icono fas fa-home"></i><p>Hogar</p></div>
            <div class="box d" id="Games"><i class="icono fas fa-gamepad"></i><p>Videojuegos</p></div>
            <div class="box e" id="Tecno"><i class="icono fas fa-laptop"></i><p>Tecnologia</p></div>
            <div class="box f"  id="Licor"><i class="icono fas fa-beer"></i><p>Licores</p></div>
            <div class="box g" id="Tools"><i class="icono fas fa-toolbox"></i><p>Herramientas</p></div>
            <div class="box h" id="Instrumentos"><i class="icono fas fa-guitar"></i><p>Instrumentos</p></div>
            <div class="box i" id="Recaudo"><i class="icono fas fa-bus-alt"></i><p>Recaudo Monterrey</p></div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Intente llamar de la forma en que sugeriste, pero lo hice con un 'box' primeramente, y con un '#box', no intente con el punto antes del nombre. 
Gracias, Me fue muy Útil.
Saludos

Comment: Te explico, es que el "#" antes del nombre es para llamar un elemento mediante su id, el "." antes del nombre es para llamar un elemento mediante su clase.

Comment: Créeme que lo llevare bien presente, Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes Utilizar `attr` para acceder al atributo id

ejemplo:

```
$(function () {
$(document).on('click', '.box', function () {
       alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Comment: La anterior función me devuelve el Id Que necesito pero detrás de el me devuelve la jerarquía de Div (Igual que Como el Prop)

Answer (score 2):

Ya te han dado las soluciones correctas en mi opinión, que básicamente implican cambiar el selector. El problema es que asignando el listener a `div`, se asigna el evento a todos los divs, incluidos todos los hijos y todos padres que existan. Otra forma de solucionarlo (no ideal en este caso) sería evitar la propagación entre padres e hijos con la función `stopPropagation()` del evento, en este caso click:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'div', function(e) {
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-content" id="Categoria">
  <div class="box" id="Music"><i class="icono fas fa-music"></i>
    <p>Audio & Video</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box b" id="Sport"><i class="icono fas fa-futbol"></i>
    <p>Deportes</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box c" id="Home"><i class="icono fas fa-home"></i>
    <p>Hogar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box d" id="Games"><i class="icono fas fa-gamepad"></i>
    <p>Videojuegos</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box e" id="Tecno"><i class="icono fas fa-laptop"></i>
    <p>Tecnologia</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box f" id="Licor"><i class="icono fas fa-beer"></i>
    <p>Licores</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box g" id="Tools"><i class="icono fas fa-toolbox"></i>
    <p>Herramientas</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box h" id="Instrumentos"><i class="icono fas fa-guitar"></i>
    <p>Instrumentos</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box i" id="Recaudo"><i class="icono fas fa-bus-alt"></i>
    <p>Recaudo Monterrey</p>
  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya ésta pregunta está excelentemente respondida, pero quisiera participar también, ya que quizás alguien buscando en Google encuentre éste tema, y quiera probar otra solución sin implementar jQuery, y definiendo solamente los id de cada elemento:

> Sin jQuery:

```
<script>
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

var myFunction = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var attribute = this.getAttribute("id");
    alert(attribute);
};

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
</script>
```

Espero le sirva a alguien más.
Nota complementaria:
Es necesario ubicar el código debajo de los elementos a clickear.

Comment: Dato no menor: no estamos en _reddit_, por lo tanto esto no es un hilo, sino una pregunta con respuestas :)

Comment: Corregido! Gracias @padaleiana , es importante ser bien claro en lo que se explica y en el uso de términos.